# Is header('Location: ../page.php?param='.$param); vulnerable to unvalidated redirects?

Tags: web-application, php, url-redirection

I have reviewed a web application built on PHP. It redirects to different pages this way:

```
$param = $_POST['param'];
header('Location: ../page.php?param='.$param);
```

Is it vulnerable to unvalidated redirects? In other words, can I redirect to another web site, manipulating the parameter `param`?

Comment: Have you tried it?   Does it work?

Comment: it depends on where $param comes from.  Normally we're concerned about user A redirecting user B.  But we're not concerned about user A redirecting user A.

Comment: @Xander I didn't try it, firstly because my job is code review, second I don't have any idea how to exploit it.

Comment: @SteveSether $param comes from an form input, this parameter must be an integer, but there isn't a validation for this parameter..

Comment: If it should always be an integer, there is no reason not to validate it.

Comment: @hmrojas.p You're never really going to understand what's going on unless you try to exploit this.  You've provided a tiny code snippet that doesn't really provide much context.  I have my doubts that it's exploitable merely because the parameter is already inside a query string.  But then again, who knows?  This is why you need to go further in your analysis and understanding, and why you can't simply stop at code review to know what the problems are.

Comment: @SteveSether Yeah you right, maybe I don't explain it very well, I do code review and penetration testing, but as I told you, I don't have any idea how to test it, for this reason I asked this question, I wanted to know if someone would know if this kind of redirection is vulnerable to "Unvalidated Redirects" and how to test it.

Comment: @hmrojas.p Well, my advice is still to try to play around with it.  See how it flows through, try some test cases.  See what actually appears in the URL.  People aren't execution environments, so it's important to actually run the code and try things.  If you're a penetration tester, this is just part of penetration testing.  We all start from ignorance, and slowly build up.  Real world answers are rarely simple, and getting them requires investigation and self expansion.

Comment: @SteveSether thanks for your comments, I just wanted a little help about this, but your recommendations are good for my career, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a risk for an open redirect vulnerability, since anything after the `?` will be interpreted as query parameters and not a part of the path. But you should change your code anyway, since you do not make sure that the `param` is actually URL-encoded. Do this with [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
header('Location: ../page.php?param='.urlencode($param));
```

However, if you use a version of PHP older than 5.1.2 you are vulnerable to header injection (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-changelog)). By sending a `param` that includes a newline an attacker could set multiple headers (or just set the location header again, overwriting the old value). Using `urlencode()` fixes that since `\n` would be encoded as `%0A`.

The whole construct could be unnecessary though - perhaps you can just check both `$_POST` and `$_GET` for `param` in `page.php`?

Comment: My guess is you're right, but the more cautious answer is "who knows".  You can't do any real analysis from a code snippet.  How do you know what happens after the snippet, and before the snippet?

Comment: @SteveSether I think the level of agnostisism you call for is unwarranted. I can say that the above code will not set the location header to another domain, no matter what code is above or below the snippet. If you disagree with my answer, you are offcourse welcome to write your own.

Comment: I was with you until the last paragraph. It could be that `page.php` is only redirected to under certain circumstances (e.g. other parameters not in the posted code snippet).

Comment: @SilverlightFox Fair point, I have toned it down to more of a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Yes, but it depends. We don't have a `page.php` code so we can only guess what that page does in the background. Still, any parameter sent either through POST or GET (or any other request for that matter) is allowed to be edited by end-used. So manipulation is of course possible. Read more about [POST (HTTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) and [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) if you want to know more.

Why: From the snippet you've posted, we can see that no escape for the POST parameter is set. That way, attacker can set the POST parameter to any value.

To exploit it, you can use **curl** or **postman** and set any value on the `$_POST['param']` parameter.

Comment: Being about to set the value of the parameter does not equal unvalidated redirect.

Comment: I think the question is about open redirects, and not vulnerabilities in general. So whats in page.php is irrelevant - if the user was redirected to it the redirect was not used to redirect the user somewhere else.